# Yearly Archive for Categories with dropdown

Tags: categories, archives

this is my first post, I already read a lot of threads and tried a few ways but none of them worked.
I have a website with two pages, which show the posts of a categorie "news" and the other one shows posts of the category "galerie".
This works so far, I also managed to create a dropdown where you can select a year and it also shows the correct number of posts, but when clicking on it, it justs redirects me to http://diefreunde.websolute.at/2016 for example, and it then shows posts of both categories.
I would like to be able to have a dropdown box as I already have, which redirects me from /news to /news/2016 or /category/news/2016 would also be possible, but I can't solve this problem.
Has anyone ever tried something similar?